# print only last item of each duplicate in foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-2

I have a very simple array but with some duplicate entries.
I just want to print the comments column at the end of each duplicate item. I am using php framework codeigniter v3.

Please see the following table structure:

[image]

below is the code i have tried so far but it is printing at the start of the first item.

```
    $Test_Comments = "";
    foreach($result as $value)
    {
        if ($Test_Comments != $value['Test_Comments'])
        {
            echo $value['Test_Comments'];
        }

        $Test_Comments = $value['Test_Comments'];
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
var_export($result);
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '570',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '570',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => 'Negative',
    'Test_Name' => 'Viral Marker ',
    'Test_Comments' => '<p><strong><em>Comments:</em></strong></p>
<p><em>Anti HCV,HbsAg were performed by immunochoromatographic Screeing Method. The Technique has Sensitivity of 99% and Sepcifity of 98% .Clinically&nbsp; inconsistent result should be reconfrimed by alternative method e.g (ELISA,PCR)</em></p>',
    
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '570',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '570',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => 'Negative',
    'Test_Name' => 'Viral Marker ',
    'Test_Comments' => '<p><strong><em>Comments:</em></strong></p>
<p><em>Anti HCV,HbsAg were performed by immunochoromatographic Screeing Method. The Technique has Sensitivity of 99% and Sepcifity of 98% .Clinically&nbsp; inconsistent result should be reconfrimed by alternative method e.g (ELISA,PCR)</em></p>',
    
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '464',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '464',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => '76',
    'Test_Name' => 'Random Sugar',
    'Test_Comments' => '',
    
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '340',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '340',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => '0.7',
    'Test_Name' => 'LFT-Liver Functions Tests',
    'Test_Comments' => '',
    
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '340',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '340',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => '0.5',
    'Test_Name' => 'LFT-Liver Functions Tests',
    'Test_Comments' => '',
    
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '340',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '340',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => '0.2',
    'Test_Name' => 'LFT-Liver Functions Tests',
    'Test_Comments' => '',
    
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '340',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '340',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => '29',
    'Test_Name' => 'LFT-Liver Functions Tests',
    'Test_Comments' => '',
    
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '340',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '340',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => '32',
    'Test_Name' => 'LFT-Liver Functions Tests',
    'Test_Comments' => '',
    
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '340',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '340',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => '164',
    'Test_Name' => 'LFT-Liver Functions Tests',
    'Test_Comments' => '',
    
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '124',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '124',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => '0.7',
    'Test_Name' => 'RFT-Renal Function Tests',
    'Test_Comments' => '',
    
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '124',
    'Patient_ID' => '4558',
    'Test_ID' => '124',
    'Test_Status' => 'Performed',
    'Head_ID' => '4769',
    'Result_Value' => '23',
    'Test_Name' => 'RFT-Renal Function Tests',
    'Test_Comments' => '',
    
  ),

)
```

Comment: Can you show `var_export() ` of your array please?

Comment: `$value['Test_Comments ']` !== `$value['Test_Comments']` Note the trailing space

Comment: @nice_dev question updated. Please see edit

Comment: Well its probably got something to do with most of the `'Test_Comments' => '',`

Comment: @RiggsFolly not all tests has comments, only few has comments, you can ignore the empty comments

Comment: Then you only have 2 that have comments, and they are both the same so will print only one of them

Comment: Yes that is the requirement actually how can i print only one at the end of each duplicate?

Comment: Surely, that is what you are doing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236840/discussion-between-shafat-ahmad-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: @ShafatAhmad Did my answer help? If yes, can you mark it as accepted so others know it is a working solution?

Comment: its not a solution. can you explain more?

Comment: @ShafatAhmad It does work. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes i have tried but not worked as my requirement.

Comment: @ShafatAhmad The code gives last comment made for each ID. See here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c7d3be2c9c130904a3d6e59783002bf7fd136310

Comment: It is merging the rows i want to print all rows but the comments only under the last row of each duplicate.

Comment: Share your expected output for the given input

Comment: check this link for better clarification: (https://nimb.ws/nQ3YPj)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236894/discussion-between-shafat-ahmad-and-nice-dev).

Comment: @ShafatAhmad I think I understood the requirement correctly. I have changed `ID` to `Test_ID` in my answer. Does it work now? Also, expected output is expected to be in terms of an array in your case and not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to re-index the array according to the `ID` key. It will always keep last occurrence with it for each `ID` yielding you the  last comment for each `ID` each time.

You can later on operate with [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on it to remove IDs as keys.

```
<?php

$result= array_values(array_column($result, null, 'Test_ID'));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This does assume the OP didnt just throw the data together in a hurry, but if they didnt :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you elaborate?